# PDF: automatically remove pages 2+4 and then glue back together?

Tags: pdf, merge, pdflatex

I have a bunch of PDFs and for each of them, I would like to remove pages 2 and 4, then glue the PDF back together. Is there a clever way to do this using a command-line utility?

Answer (score 2):

The [PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can do this from the command line:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat 1 3 output output.pdf
```

`cat 1 3` extracts pages 1 and 3 from `input.pdf` and outputs it to `output.pdf`. To cycle through all on Windows, use

```
for %f in (*.pdf) do pdftk %f cat 1 3 output %~nfo.pdf
```

`%~nf` returns an extension-less version of `%f` as extracted from the list `*.pdf`. Therefore, using `%~nfo.pdf` produces, as `output`, a file `<input>o.pdf` for input `<input>.pdf`. For using inside a batch file, use `%%f` and `%%~nfo.pdf`.

For more information, see the [PDF Toolkit man page](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/).

Answer (score 0):

[PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=3) and more specifically `pdfsam-console` mentioned on that page can do this.

Comment: Note that this requires JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from what you said, I think you can use a PDF Merger. How? You just offer the page range of your pdf file except for page 2 and 4. for example 1,3,5-last page number. Then merge them, thus you will get desired part and delete 2 and 4.
Do as what I state! It's very easy to achieve!

you may try [PDF Merger:](https://web.archive.org/web/20150809065415/http://www.convertpdf.org:80/pdf-merger)

> The PDF Merger is a professional but easy-to-use PDF file Combiner &
> Joiner designed to merge PDF files for more convenient organizing,
> archiving and printing in batch. It allows you to merge PDF according
> to your needs with many different merge modes. With it you are
> flexible to merge multiple PDF files to create a single one or merge
> specific pages to a new PDF file, even merge any pages of several
> different PDF files to one.